# Ruby 1.9.3 memory issue

Tags: ruby, memory-management, heap-memory, ui-testing

We're having many automation libraries which can automate devices and we have some automation scripts which are running from a decade.

Recently we are trying to integrate multiple devices and perform automation. When we run our scripts which independent to specific device separately we don't have any issue, but when we run the scripts which are specific to more than device we are facing the issue.

*Issue:*

During the batch executions after a specific point (after execution of 5 or 6 scripts) the execution got terminated without any error.

Later on our investigation we found that memory lagging could be issue and we have increased the Heap size of ruby, but still no luck.

This is how we have increased the Heap slots and size.

[image]

Comment: I mean, an obvious question could be, why not upgrade to modern ruby and take advantage of the decade of work that's gone into improving memory consumption (amongst many other things)?

Comment: Hi @TomLord, as you said we should have done that very long back, but now we cannot go for a sudden change of our execution platform. However we are also migrating the things which supports new platform and new environment, but still there are some legacy things we have to maintain and they require old libraries and old version of Ruby. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't shown any code, or any diagnostics of the memory usage. This may be an XY problem, for all I know. And I haven't attempted ruby 1.9 memory tweaking in many years, so I can't really remember much about potential quirks/pitfalls in the configuration.

Comment: I think source is not required for this query. Moreover there is nothing to deal with source code. Because our source code doesn't perform any of the actions on ruby memory or heap organization. From our route cause analysis on execution termination we found 'low memory allocation to ruby', causing script to terminate during run. So, we have provided new values for heap growth factor through system environment variables. After setting those values given in the query we could able to some execution count during batch execution, before setting those values there is 0% execution of scripts.

Comment: @TomLord, Also there is an another observation point, if we run the script individually(one script at a time) we could see a perfect execution but if run the script as a batch we are facing this issue(script terminates without any error)

Comment: @TomLord, I would like to have some tips, to analyse ruby object maps, memory allocations, increasing ruby heap memory during runtime, etc... Can help if you have any info? or what do you think the route cause for this issue. or Give some tips to identify the route cause.

Comment: I think the source code is relevant because the code obviously does something that leads to memory issues. Often it is just a simple thing: a global variable, big array, too much data loaded into memory...

Comment: @EVNRaja *"I think source is not required for this query."* --- And I think that it is. It's not "normal" for code to suffer from memory issues like this; You *must* be going *something unusual* that causes the problem. But I have no idea what that is without seeing the code.

Comment: *For example*, maybe you're reading large files into memory at once, and could instead be loading them in chunks. One workaround could be to run scripts one at a time, or somehow allocate more memory to the ruby program; a better solution would be to fix the underlying code design.

Comment: @TomLord, thank you, for responding to this query, as suggested we will try with latest ruby version